# Catching an exception from another running Java application

Tags: java, exception

I've run into the issue where I have a program (not written by me, by someone else) I want to run 24/7, but sometimes it crashes. Normally, this wouldn't be an issue because I can simply create a process watcher that checks if it crashed, and then restarts it if necessary.

But, this particular program sometimes throws an exception and outputs it into the graphical interface that's integrated into it. In this instance, the program doesn't crash at all. The interface stays up, but the actual server functionality is unavailable.

Is there any way I can intercept this information from this process?

Comment: do you have access to the source code of this app? and if so - can you modify it?

Comment: @Windle: This is running on Windows 7, but I can just as easily run this in Linux as well. I'd prefer a solution for Windows though.

Comment: @aav: No, I am not the developer of it. The program is closed source.

Comment: maybe it would make sense to check it's "server functionality" and do something, when it is not any longer available?

Comment: @aav: Unfortunately the only way I can check the actual server requires a human to be there. I don't have any programmatic way of interfacing with the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [Java Virtual Machine Tools Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/). I can't give you the code to catch your exception, but this is where to look. You'll have to do some detective work to find the class that throws the exception, or at least to find some indicator that it has been thrown.

Edit: You can also try calling the vendor to see if they know of a way. You can also look to see if it is writing the exception to a log file, which you could then watch.

Comment: I'll take a look into this. I know the specific exception it's throwing, since it's throwing it out in full detail to the GUI. I'm only concerned really with this one exception, since the server isn't handling it in any way.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have no access to the source code, so if it is outputting to the GUI the answer is no. Even if you could attach to the running process you would need to intercept the exception, but it is caught and sent to the GUI, not thrown from the application.

In theory, you could screen scrape the application. I don't know of any specific tools for doing this, but they may be out there.

Edit: I may have been wrong above, check out a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421422/finding-running-instances-in-a-running-jvm) where they get the stack from a running thread. You probably won't be able to capture the exception this way, but if you're lucky the stack trace will look very different when the program is operating normally compared to when an exception has been thrown.

Edit 2: I submitted a second, more accurate answer. See below.

Comment: My guess is this is the best route to go. If it does print to System.err/out you're going to see a lot of output and you can kill the process (removing the GUI elements created).

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not work, but if when the application displays it's error and the server stops working does the memory usage drop? If so you could probably just add some logic to your process monitor to call the windows command `tasklist` to see if the memory usage drops below some threshold. You'll have to check how much memory the program normally uses and how much it uses after the error though.

Since you said the server functionality stops working, another option could be to write a simple program that basically just pings the server how ever often you want to make sure it is still up. If not, kill the process and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the other program Java? Look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), you may be able to hack something using it if you have control on the program startup.

Comment: The only control I have is an executable file that I can run. Would this still be possible?

Comment: AspectJ only works on Java. If this is Windows Executable you will probably have to keep a look-out for a Window Title and kill then restart the process.

Comment: I would, but it doesn't work that way. It outputs it to a text box in the interface, not the title.

Comment: Is that other process a Java program?

Comment: Yes, the server that's running is a Java program, as I said in my original post.

Comment: I am sorry. The title says Java application but your question only mentions program written by someone else. If this is unobfuscated Java there may be many different possibilities. Do take a look at `AspectJ`. You can put an advice on the constructor(s) of the `Exception` reported in the stack trace and create some other output that your monitor program can look at. You might even be able to replace the definition of the Exception altogether, even call `Runtime.Exit` so that the program exits. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Without ability to rebuild the app you are generally out of luck unless you do some extensive hacking. Here is one option I can think of.

Most likely the application replaces System.out and/or System.err with its own stream implementation. If that's the case you can try to locate the class for this stream and replace it with your own wrapper with the same name. You may rename original class using jarjar. In the wapper you can provide console output to detect the exception.

Comment: If it is a Java program and you have an executable, chances are it is wrapped. Check out Launch4J as there's a pretty good chance that's what they used. It might not be impossible to extract the jar (licensing aside).